# Bazel: Make genrule outputs available to another rule

Tags: bazel

I need the outputs of a `genrule` to be available **next to** another rule. (i.e. a `py_binary`).

Suppose we have these files:

```py
# root/gen/BUILD:
genrule(
  name = "gen",
  outs = ["a.txt", "a2.txt"],
  cmd = "cd $(RULEDIR) && echo salam > a.txt && echo hello > a2.txt",
)

# root/BUILD:
py_binary(
  name = "use",
  srcs = ["use.py"],
  data = ["gen:a.txt", "gen:a2.txt"],
)

# use.py:
f = open("a.txt", "r")
f2 = open("a2.txt", "r")
print(f.read())
print(f2.read())
```

At a glance:

```
project
├── root
│   ├── BUILD
│   ├── gen
│   │   └── BUILD  << This can generate required 'a.txt' and 'a2.txt' 
|   |                 files.
│   └── use.py  << This script needs to access a.txt file as './a.txt',
|                  but with 'bazel run root:use' it should access files
|                  like 'root/gen/a.txt'.
└── WORKSPACE
```

When I run `bazel run :use`, it doesn't find the file:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'a.txt'
```

It needs to have `a.txt` and `a2.txt` files **nearby**, but they are in `bazel-bin/gen` directory.

Answer (score 0):

You could set [output_to_bindir](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/general.html#genrule.output_to_bindir) in your `genrule` so that the output files will be written into the `bazel-bin` directory instead of the `bazel-genfiles` directory and then reference them in `use.py` using their  relative path in the workspace, e.g.:

```py
# root/gen/BUILD
genrule(
  name = "gen",
  ...
  output_to_bindir = True,
)

# use.py:
f = open("root/gen/a.txt", "r")
f2 = open("root/gen/a2.txt", "r")
print(f.read())
print(f2.read())
```

This should allow the application to load the files when running through `bazel run`.

Comment: Thanks. but my question is: How to reference the generated files **nearby**? Suppose I can't or shouldn't change the code. Something like copying them to root directory... maybe

Comment: I see. In that case I wouldn't know how to output `a.txt` directly into `bazel-bin` (I believe `genrule` does not allow that from an inner project, but I could be wrong), sorry.

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot modify the code in the py_binary, you could write a genrule that creates a link to the other file, e.g.:

```
genrule(
  name = "link_a.txt",
  srcs = ["//gen/a.txt"]
  outs = ["a.txt"],
  cmd = "ln $< $@"
)

genrule(
  name = "link_a2.txt",
  srcs = ["//gen/a2.txt"]
  outs = ["a2.txt"],
  cmd = "ln $< $@"
)
```

(`$<` is a shortcut for "the path to the input file if there is only one", and similarly `$@` is a shortcut for "the path to the output file if there is only one")

It's also possible to wrap the genrule in a reusable macro, or do fancier things in Starlark, if needed.

Comment: What does it mean linking "input directory" to "output directory"? However, the python rule needs the generated files at **run time** near it. It's not about **build time**

Comment: Updated question. *At a glance* section may clarify my question

Comment: `bazel run` will run the binary at the root of the "execution root" (see `bazel info execution_root`), so even if `a.txt` and `a2.txt` are next to the binary, `open("a.txt")` won't work because the current working directory won't be the location of the binary. You'll need to either `cd` to the directory and run the script there (`cd bazel-bin/root; ./use`), or write a `sh_binary` that does that for you

Comment: "the python rule needs the generated files at run time near it. It's not about build time". Putting `data = ["a.txt", "a2.txt"]` on the `py_binary` makes the files available at runtime